# ImportError of module libscrc on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, libraries

I'm kinda new to Rpi's and I have a problem executing a library called libscrc with python (I use python3), I need this to calculate a crc checksum for my RS485 communication. On pycharm on my PC everything works fine, but when I implement this on my RPI3 I get errors, I already managed to install the pyserial library and this works fine, but I keep getting errors when trying to run libscrc (this is the link to the library: https://pypi.org/project/libscrc/ ). This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Rs_485.py", line 1, in <module>
    import libscrc
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/libscrc/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ._crcx  import *
ImportError: libpython3.6m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help me? I already updated and upgraded the RPI.
When I try the following test command

> pi@raspberrypi:~/codes $ python -m libscrc.testmodbus

I get:

> /usr/bin/python: No module named libscrc

And I'm using python3.6 by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a try by using the github link of the libscrc project

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/hex-in/libscrc.git
```

It worked this way for me! cheers!

Comment: Thank you!! :) but it also worked with my method above, I don't know why, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was found! Hope this wil help anyone out with the same problem!

Use this command!:

```
sudo apt-get install libpython3.6
```

this did the job for me! :)

Comment: That's a little odd because if you have Python 3.6 installed you should already have libpython3.6 as well... Or on Raspian is the default Python interpreter statically linked?  That I'm not sure.